# How can I update wrapperlist item

Tags: wrapper-class, repeat

How can I update the wrapperlist item with the value of the second for loop? Always the wrapper adds the whole information (see my screenshot). Also I don't know how can I display the result at a visualforce page? It is not possible with apex:repeat.

```
public class Radial_Analyse_Test {
    
    public List<ResultWrapper> resultList   {get; set;}
    
    public Radial_Analyse_Test(){
        Radial_Analyse_output(); 
    }
      
    public class ResultWrapper {
        public Decimal Network_2021 {get; set;}
        public Decimal Network_2022 {get; set;}
    }
       
    public void Radar_Analyse_output() {
        
        //Id AccId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');              
        Id AccId = '0011x00001LuukeAAB';    // for test        
        Decimal Network_2021 = 0;
        Decimal Network_2022 = 0;
        
        Map<Id, List<ResultWrapper>> KscCatsToWrapper = new Map<Id, List<ResultWrapper>>();
        Set<String>KscCats = new Set<String>();
        
        for (Scorecard__c ksc1: [SELECT Id, Name, Account__c, Year__c, Network__c FROM Scorecard__c where Account__c = :AccId and Year__c = 2021]) {
            KscCats.add(AccId);
            ResultWrapper wrap  = new ResultWrapper();
            wrap.Network_2021   = ksc1.Network__c; 
            KscCatsToWrapper.put(AccId, new List<ResultWrapper>());
            KscCatsToWrapper.get(AccId).add(wrap);
        }
        system.debug('KscCats 2021: ' + KscCats);
        system.debug('KscWrapper 2021: ' + KscCatsToWrapper);
        system.debug('-------------------------------------');
        
        
        for (Scorecard__c ksc2: [SELECT Id, Name, Account__c, Year__c, Network__c FROM Scorecard__c where Account__c = :AccId and Year__c = 2022]) {
            KscCats.add(AccId);
            ResultWrapper wrap  = new ResultWrapper();
            wrap.Network_2022   = ksc2.Network__c;
            if(!KscCatsToWrapper.containsKey(AccId)){
                KscCatsToWrapper.put(AccId,new List<ResultWrapper>());
                KscCatsToWrapper.get(AccId).add(wrap);
            } else {
                KscCatsToWrapper.get(AccId).add(wrap);               
            }           
            system.debug('KscCats 2022: ' + KscCats);
            system.debug('KscWrapper 2022: ' + KscCatsToWrapper);
            system.debug('-------------------------------------');
        }
}
```

[image: debug]

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" Controller="Radial_Analyse_Test" showHeader="true" id="pg">
    <center>
        <apex:repeat value="{!resultlist}" var="w">
            {!w.Network_2021}
        </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

**CURRENT**
At the end of the query I want to add the data to a radial chart.
Currently I do it like below, but it works not good, because I have

```
public Radial_Analyse() {
    
    Id AccId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); 
    
    data = new List<RadialData>();
    List<Scorecard__c> KSCList = new List<Scorecard__c>();
    KSCList = [SELECT Name, Year__c, Employee__c, Network__c, Sales__c FROM Scorecard__c where Account__c = :AccId];
    for(Scorecard__c KSC : KSCList) {
        data.add(new RadialData('Employee', KSC.Employee__c));
        data.add(new RadialData('Network', KSC.Network__c));
        data.add(new RadialData('Sales', KSC.Sales__c));
    }

    public class RadialData {
        String  Score_Category {get;set;}
        Decimal Score   {get;set;}
        
        public RadialData(String Score_Category, Decimal Score) {
            this.Score_Category= Score_Category;
            this.Score = Score;
        }
    }  
}
```

**FUTURE**
I think the result should like this, but I don't know how can I split the wrapper.

```
public class RadialData {
    String Score_Category {get; set;}
    Decimal Score_2021   {get;set;}
    Decimal Score_2022   {get;set;}
    
    public RadialData(String Score_Category, Decimal Score_2021, Decimal Score_2022) {
        this.Score_Category = Score_Category;
        this.Score_2021 = Score_2021;
        this.Score_2022 = Score_2022;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 02.08.2022**

Wrapper

```
06:09:57:422 USER_DEBUG [75]|DEBUG|KscWrapper 2022: {2021=(ResultWrapper:[Employee=2, Network=8, Sales=5]), 2022=(ResultWrapper:[Employee=1, Network=6, Sales=5])}
```

split wrapper into years

```
06:09:57:424 USER_DEBUG [83]|DEBUG|network 2021 --> (ResultWrapper:[Employee=2, Network=8, Sales=5])
06:09:57:424 USER_DEBUG [84]|DEBUG|network 2022 --> (ResultWrapper:[Employee=1, Network=6, Sales=5])
```

that looks good, but now when I try to get a specific value of the year like KscCatsToWrapper.get(2021).get('Network'));
I get an error **Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(String) from the type List<Radial_Analyse_Test.ResultWrapper>**

Comment: the values are only grouped by AccId right now. So for each AccId, ResultWrapper for both years are added to the list. What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: @GuyClairbois I add some more Information to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code is for 1 account at a time anyway, why do you organize into a map of `<Id,List<ResultWrapper>>` where Id is the accountId? That's not needed.

And if you then want to have results per year, why not organize into a  `Map<String,List<ResultWrapper>>` where the String is the year? (or you could even user an integer of the year as the map key).

Then later on, when you need a list of values for 1 year, you simply do `resultList = KscCatsToWrapper.get('2021')`  ( or `resultList = KscCatsToWrapper.get(2021)` if you use integers).

Then, lastly, if you also want to split the scores into categories, it would be beneficial to include those as a map key as well. So a nested map: `Map<String,Map<String,List<ResultWrapper>>>`

That will require a bit more organisation but you can find enough examples online.

Eventually when you need the value you can do `KscCatsToWrapper.get('Network').get('2021')`

Comment: thanks, I deleted the id of the account and add the year as keyset. I add some more details of my debug in my question. How can I get a specific value of a year?